# What is this distribution type?: try $(n+1)$ trial when event occured at $n$ trial with probability $p$?

Tags: probability

As the title describes.

For example, I have a coin with $p(\mathrm{head})=0.5$, $p(\mathrm{tail})=0.5$. I toss a coin for the first time and if the tail is observed, I go on the second trial. If the head is observed I stop the coin-toss. I can do this experiment, for example, 1000 times and count how many trials have been done at each experiment. Then, I can plot a distribution of "count" vs "number of trials".

What is this distribution type called? I first thought that it is binomial distribution, but it is not. $B(n,p)$ has a fixed number of trials $n$, while the example has a variable number of trials.

Comment: I think you look after geometric distribution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is called a [geometric distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_distribution).